# Float to Varchar in SQL Server with our Rounding or Padding in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to convert Float value to Varchar in SQL Server with our Rounding or Padding in SQL Server .

```
DECLARE @A AS FLOAT, @B AS FLOAT

SELECT @A=1.353954 , @B=1.353
SELECT 
CAST(@A AS VARCHAR(40)) AS B_FLOAT_TO_VARCHAR, -- Rounding
STR(@B, 25, 5) -- Padding 0's
```

Actual Result   : 1.35395, 1.35300

Expected Result : 1.353954, 1.353

Answer (score 1):

Float is an approximate datatype so this is always going to be a bit tricky. You could convert your float to a numeric and then to a varchar. It works for these values but won't for every float value.

```
select convert(varchar(10), convert(numeric(9,6), @A))
    , convert(varchar(10), @B)
```

Answer (score 0):

First cast as decimal and specify the length of the decimal you have

```
DECLARE @A AS FLOAT, @B AS FLOAT

SELECT @A=1.353954 , @B=1.353
SELECT 
cast(CAST(@A AS decimal(9,6)) as varchar(max)) AS B_FLOAT_TO_VARCHAR,  -- Rounding
cast(CAST(@B AS decimal(9,3)) as varchar(max))
```

Comment: HI, Length of the after decimal is not a known value. It could be 99.345 or 99.45678

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server 2008, you can use the 128 or 129 style:

```
DECLARE @A AS FLOAT, @B AS FLOAT
SELECT @A=1.353954 , @B=1.353

SELECT CONVERT(varchar(50), @A, 128) [A]
      ,CONVERT(varchar(50), @B, 128) [B]
```

Produces:

```
A         B
1.353954  1.353
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql

Comment: this will work, but using those styles is deprecated: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql#float-and-real-styles.  See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174450%28v=sql.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 for what 128 does (search for 128)

Comment: I already knew that and answered the question correctly for OP's version of SQL Server 2008.  There's a 'new code' for the newest editions of SQL Server, you would just use that code instead.